# i get data foreach and want set key input is $key.But i have a error.This is my code of me at blade laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i get data foreach and want set key input is $key.But i have a error.This is my code of me at blade laravel.

```
    @foreach ($typeCost->typeCostCompany as $key => $item)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">{!! $key + 1 !!}</td>
    
                                            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;width :200px">
                                                {{-- {!! Form::select('company_id[]', ['' => trans('system.dropdown_choice')] + $companies, old('company_id[]', $item->company_id), ['class' => 'form-control select2']) !!} --}}
                                                {!! Form::select('company_id[$key][]', $companies, old('company_id[]', explode(' ', $item->company_id)), ['class' => 'form-control select2','multiple', 'required']) !!}
                                            </td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: what error do you have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.